# Integrating 2d exponential function symbolically with polynomials of 2nd order running for days

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I'm trying to integrate this function by Mathematica

```
f[X1_, P1_, X2_, P2_, r_, φ_, θ_, η_] := 
 1/π^2 E^(-(P1 Sqrt[1 - η] + P2 Sqrt[η])^2 - (X1 Sqrt[
      1 - η] + 
     X2 Sqrt[η])^2 + (-(P2 Sqrt[1 - η] - 
         P1 Sqrt[η])^2 - (X2 Sqrt[1 - η] - 
        X1 Sqrt[η])^2) Cosh[
     2 r] + ((-P2^2 (-1 + η) + 
         X2^2 (-1 + η) + (P1 - X1) (P1 + X1) η - 
         2 P1 P2 Sqrt[(1 - η) η] + 
         2 X1 X2 Sqrt[(1 - η) η]) Cos[
        2 θ - 2 φ] - 
      2 (P2 X2 (-1 + η) - P1 X1 η + 
         P2 X1 Sqrt[(1 - η) η] + 
         P1 X2 Sqrt[-(-1 + η) η]) Sin[
        2 θ - 2 φ]) Sinh[2 r])
```

[image: Formula in traditional form]

The command is

```
Integrate[
 f[X1, P1, X2, P2, 
  r, φ, θ, η], {X2, -∞, ∞}, \
{P2, -∞, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  r ∈ Reals && X1 ∈ Reals && 
   P1 ∈ Reals && φ ∈ 
    Reals && θ ∈ Reals && 0 <= η <= 1 && 
   r >= 0 && η ∈ Reals]
```

Mathematica version 10.0.2.0, 64 Bit Win 7, Intel i7. The integration is running since 3.5 days already. Looking at the system monitor, one core is busy, but the memory is static (816 MB). What I was trying before was to use a Fourier Transform, the differentiation rule "in reverse" to get the integration, and then transform back. This wasn't working either.
If someone has an idea how to tackle this with Mathematica in another way, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance it seems hopeless - you have all those hyperbolic trig and regular trig functions in your exponent.  But then you notice that that is all superfluous since the only two variables you care about, `X2` and `P2` don't go into any of those functions, so that other stuff is just a distraction.  `{X1,P1,r, φ, θ, η}` are all just constants!

What you are really doing is just a two-dimensional Gaussian integral, which aren't that difficult.  There are specific criteria that need to be met in order for them to have a solution though.

This is the integral you want to solve,

```
Integrate[(1/(π^2)) Exp[a1 + a2 X2+a3 P2 + a4 X2 P2 + a5 X2^2 + a6 P2^2],{X2,-∞,∞},{P2,-∞,∞}]
```

which give a `ConditionalExpression` as the solution.  That is, provided

$$\Re\left(\frac{\text{a4}^2}{\text{a6}}-4 \text{a5}\right)>0$$

the solution is

$$\frac{2 \exp \left(\frac{\text{a1} \left(\text{a4}^2-4 \text{a5} \text{a6}\right)+\text{a2}^2 \text{a6}-\text{a2} \text{a3} \text{a4}+\text{a3}^2 \text{a5}}{\text{a4}^2-4 \text{a5} \text{a6}}\right)}{\pi  \sqrt{-\text{a6}} \sqrt{\frac{\text{a4}^2}{\text{a6}}-4 \text{a5}}}$$

Now all you need to do is express `{a1,..,a6}` in terms of `{X1,P1,r, φ, θ, η}`.  For this, we just do a series expansion of the argument of your exponent in terms of `X2` and `P2`.

```
arg=-(P1 Sqrt[1-η]+P2 Sqrt[η])^2-(X1 Sqrt[1-η]+X2 Sqrt[η])^2+(-(P2 Sqrt[1-η]-P1 Sqrt[η])^2-(X2 Sqrt[1-η]-X1 Sqrt[η])^2) Cosh[2 r]
+((-P2^2 (-1+η)+X2^2 (-1+η)+(P1-X1) (P1+X1) η-2 P1 P2 Sqrt[(1-η) η]+2 X1 X2 Sqrt[(1-η) η]) Cos[2 θ-2 φ]
-2 (P2 X2 (-1+η)-P1 X1 η+P2 X1 Sqrt[(1-η) η]+P1 X2 Sqrt[-(-1+η) η]) Sin[2 θ-2 φ]) Sinh[2 r];

coeff[nx2_,np2_]:=SeriesCoefficient[arg,{X2,0,nx2},{P2,0,np2}]
```

(someone needs to show me how to easily copy and paste from a notebook into this page and retain the Greek letters)

First to deal with the condition for the solution to be valid,

```
FullSimplify[-4 a5 + a4^2/a6 /. {a1 -> coeff[0, 0], a2 -> coeff[1, 0],
a3 -> coeff[0, 1], a4 -> coeff[1, 1], a5 -> coeff[2, 0], 
  a6 -> coeff[0, 2]}, 
Assumptions -> 
  r ∈ Reals && X1 ∈ Reals && 
  P1 ∈ Reals && φ ∈ 
Reals && θ ∈ Reals && 0 <= η <= 1 && 
  r >= 0 && η ∈ Reals]

(* Out[] = -((-4-8 (-1+η) η+8 (-1+η) η Cosh[2 r])/(η-(-1+η) Cosh[2 r]+(-1+η) Cos[2 θ-2 φ] Sinh[2 r])) *)
```

or, in LaTeX,

$$\Re\left(-\frac{-8 (\eta -1) \eta +8 (\eta -1) \eta  \cosh (2 r)-4}{\eta +(\eta -1) \sinh (2 r) \cos (2 \theta -2 \varphi )-(\eta -1) \cosh (2 r)}\right)>0$$

Assuming that condition is met, the solution is,

```
FullSimplify[(
  2 E^((-a2 a3 a4 + a3^2 a5 + a2^2 a6 + a1 (a4^2 - 4 a5 a6))/(
  a4^2 - 4 a5 a6)))/(
  Sqrt[-4 a5 + a4^2/a6] Sqrt[-a6] π) /. {a1 -> coeff[0, 0], 
  a2 -> coeff[1, 0], a3 -> coeff[0, 1], a4 -> coeff[1, 1], 
  a5 -> coeff[2, 0], a6 -> coeff[0, 2]}, 
Assumptions -> 
  r ∈ Reals && X1 ∈ Reals && 
  P1 ∈ Reals && φ ∈ 
Reals && θ ∈ Reals && 0 <= η <= 1 && 
  r >= 0 && η ∈ Reals]

(*  

Out[] = (1/π)Sqrt[1/((1 + 2 (-1 + η) η - 
2 (-1 + η) η Cosh[2 r]) (η - (-1 + η) Cosh[
  2 r] + (-1 + η) Cos[2 θ - 2 φ] Sinh[
  2 r]))] Sqrt[η - (-1 + η) Cosh[
2 r] + (-1 + η) Cos[2 θ - 2 φ] Sinh[
2 r]] (Cosh[(-(P1^2 + 
    X1^2) (1 - η + η Cosh[
      2 r]) + η ((P1 - X1) (P1 + X1) Cos[
      2 θ - 2 φ] + 
    2 P1 X1 Sin[2 θ - 2 φ]) Sinh[2 r])/(-1 - 
2 (-1 + η) η + 2 (-1 + η) η Cosh[2 r])] + 
  Sinh[((P1^2 + 
    X1^2) (1 - η + η Cosh[
      2 r]) + η ((-P1^2 + X1^2) Cos[
      2 θ - 2 φ] - 
    2 P1 X1 Sin[2 θ - 2 φ]) Sinh[2 r])/(-1 - 
2 (-1 + η) η + 2 (-1 + η) η Cosh[2 r])])

*)
```

and I can't even get this site's LaTeX to work with such wide fractions, so I'll include an image of the final result:

[image]

Comment: +1. Just what I was about to post. :)  See http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor for Greek formatting button.

Comment: Fixed the Greek letters.  Adjust line breaks etc. as you see fit.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks very much, that makes it a lot easier!

Comment: Just about the length of the result: A `TrigToExp` shortens the result a bit.